# Does operator new destruct initialized objects after an exception?

Tags: c++, exception, new-operator, destructor

I have a class `A` that allocates memory in its constructor using `new`.
What happens when I allocate a chunk of `A`s and (while `new[]` is initializing the single `A`s) one of them throws `std::bad_alloc` in their constructor?

Does `operator new[]` destruct the already initialized objects?
Or is it my duty to make sure the constructor doesn't throw?

**EDIT**: The two invocations of new might sound confusing, so here's a piece of code to clarify:

```
class A
{
    int* mem;
public:
    A()
    {
        try
        {
            mem = new int[3];
        }
        catch(bad_alloc&)
        {
            throw 5;
        }
    }
    ~A()
    {
        delete[] mem;
    }
}

A* list = 0;

try
{
    list = new A[50000];
}
catch(int)
{
    // When I get here, did the new[] above call the destructors
    // of all the objects it managed to construct before one of them threw?
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you do `new Foo()` and the constructor of `Foo` throws, then the memory allocated by the relevant `operator new` will be freed. And if the constructor for any member of Foo has succeeded, that member's destructor will be called.

If you do `new Foo[100]`, and the 42nd constructor throws, then all the already-constructed Foo objects are destroyed (in reverse order).

Comment: Yes, thanks. Edited my answer - although the short version is "yes".

Answer (score 1):

Yes, any objects already allocated will be deleted. Why not try it yourself?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdexcept>

class A {
    static int n;
public:
    A()
    {
        ++n;
        std::cout << "construncting A no. " << n << "...";
        // let's pretend we allocate something here
        // with new and it fails
        if (n == 5) {
            std::cout << std::endl;
            throw std::bad_alloc();
        }
        std::cout << "done\n";
    }
    ~A()
    {
        --n;
        std::cout << "destructed A no. " << n << "\n";
    }
};

int A::n = 0;

int main()
{
    try {
        A* a = new A[10];
    }
    catch (std::bad_alloc& e) {
        std::cout << "caught an exception!\n";
    }
}
```

However, the destructor of the instance which constructor threw will NOT be called (you can see that if you run the code above). Still, the members which were constructed by that point will be deleted. For example, if this constructor throws:

```
class foo {
    int i;
    bar* b;
public:
    foo() : i(42), b(new bar)
    {
        float f = 3.14;
        // something throws an exception here
    }
    ~foo()
    {
        delete b;
    }
};
```

`i`,`b` and `f` will be deleted, however memory that was allocated will not be freed (`delete b` doesn't get called) and you'll have a memory leak (using smart pointers will easily solve that).

Take a look at C++FaqLite for more info about this:

http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/freestore-mgmt.html#faq-16.10

http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/exceptions.html#faq-17.8

Answer (score 0):

Members will be destroyed. Automatic-duration variables in the constructor will go out of scope and be destroyed properly.

Comment: Can you explain it in layman's terms? I'm not sure I fully understand. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

If some fields have been successfully initialized with their constructors, the destructors will be called automatically.